# Same numpy version [Colab and Raspberry pi]:: BUT 'ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import'

Tags: python, numpy, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to use the trained multiclass classification model (model trained and saved from colab) into Raspberry pi 4.

In colab:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

prints `3.7.14 (default, Sep  8 2022, 00:06:44)  [GCC 7.5.0]`. Similarly,

```
import tensorflow
import numpy
print('tensorflow_version',tensorflow.__version__)
print('numpy_version',numpy.__version__)
```

prints

```
tensorflow_version 2.5.0
numpy_version 1.19.2
```

On the Raspberry Pi `(Python 3.7.0 (default, Sep 20 2022, 15:06:22)[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux),` `tensorflow.__version__`  is `'2.5.0'` and `numpy.__version__` is `'1.19.2'`.

With the above configuration, I get :

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd

ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

While searching for similar questions in StackOverflow, most of them suggest that the error is due to mismatch in `numpy` version. However, in my case, I've the same version of numpy.

Does the `GCC` version have some role in this error? How can I downgrade `GCC` version in raspberry pi or upgrade its version in colab?

Note that the version of tensorflow is fixed owing to my hardware (`armv7l`), which mandes to use `numpy 1.19.2`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by saving my classification model into `TensorflowLite` as [follows](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/convert/convert_models):

```
# Convert the model.
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Save the model.
with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```